# Can I install Office 2016 without installing Onenote 2016?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016

I need to install office 2016 for work, but I really like OneNote 2013. I don't much like OneNote 2016. Is it possible to install the rest of Office 2016 but not 2013?

Comment: You may be able to if you don't use the "Click to Run" installer for Office 2016...

Comment: OneNote and Office do not share the same installer.  You can also have multiple versions of OneNote installed,

Answer (score 0):

According to this website there is a tool that allows you to customise the Office 2013 and 2016 Click-to-Run installers:

http://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-microsoft-office-click-to-run-c2r-setup-to-install-selected-programs-only/

> Microsoft provides an official tool to customize Click-to-Run
>   installer options so that you can force the installer to install your
>   desired Office programs only.
>
> This tool is called "Office Deployment Tool" and is available for
>   Office 2013 and Office 2016 versions. With the help of this tool, you
>   can download Office setup files at your desired location and then
>   configure the installer to install your selected Office apps only.

The website contains steps to amend the XML file that is essentially an "unattend" file that provides the answers to the installer and allows you to customise what applications and settings the installer performs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the full setup.exe accept the terms of this agreement (at your own will), then click continue > Customize > Click on the down arrow next to Microsoft OneNote and choose "Not Available" then continue on with the installation as you need.